# recursions or itertool instead of for loop

Tags: python, django

I constructed a function that for a `Group` that can have parents, obtains all descendants of the given group.

Right now I use `for` loops for this, how can I make this more efficient?

my code is like this.

```
def get_group_last111(group):
        groupmap = services_models.GroupMapping.objects.filter(parent_id=group)
        group_list = [group.id]
        for each in groupmap:
            group_list.append(each.group_id)
            groupmaploop = services_models.GroupMapping.objects.filter(parent_id=each.group_id)
            if groupmaploop.exists():
                for each_data in groupmaploop:
                    group_list.append(each_data.group_id)
                    groupmaploop1= services_models.GroupMapping.objects.filter(parent_id=each_data.group_id)
                    if groupmaploop1.exists():
                        for each_data1 in groupmaploop1:
                            group_list.append(each_data1.group_id)
                            groupmaploop3= services_models.GroupMapping.objects.filter(parent_id=each_data1.group_id)
                            if groupmaploop3.exists():
                                for each_data2 in groupmaploop1:
                                    group_list.append(each_data2.group_id)
                                    groupmaploop4= services_models.GroupMapping.objects.filter(parent_id=each_data2.group_id)
                                    if groupmaploop4.exists():
                                      for each_data5 in groupmaploop4:
                                        group_list.append(each_data5.group_id)
        print set(group_list)
        return set(group_list)
```

can i do this more efficiently using itertool or recursive function.please help me

Comment: Can you first explain *what* you want? Not *how* you want it?

Comment: i want to use recursive function instead of loop inside loop.

Comment: no I mean *what result* you want. For example: "all `group_id`s that satisfiy "this" condition. It looks like this can be rewritten in a single (or perhaps 2-3) queries, this will make it magnitudes faster.

Comment: i want all the group_id.actually it works for me.but not much efficient.

Comment: but here you have limited (in the code) yourself to five "generations".

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you want *all descendants* for a given `Group` object. So the children, grandchildren, great-grandchildren, etc.

We can do this by querying in the *depth* of the relations, like:

```
def get_group_last111(group):
    result = {group.id}
    cur = result
    while cur:
        cur = set(
            GroupMapping.objects.filter(parent_id__in=cur)
                                .values_list('group_id', flat=True)
        )
        result.update(cur)
    return result
```

If there are thus four generations originating from the given `group`, then this will take four queries. We thus do not loop over the "family tree" in Python, but use queries to fetch all the groups.